# GAE Query fetch()

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to learn simple operations with the datastore and I am having problems. Can someone help why this is not working?

```
class Pet(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty

pet = Pet(name="Fluffy")

pet.put()

query = Pet.all()

results = query.fetch(limit=5)
print pet.name
```

When I run this I get

```
<class 'google.appengine.ext.db.StringProperty'>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
name = db.StringProperty
```

to

```
name = db.StringProperty()
```

Comment: Yeah, it had more to do with the data model than with fetch()